# XSL condition statement

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements

i have a problem with this statement :

```
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="cars[@id='1']">    
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="cars[@id='1']='1'">true</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
      true
 </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

"True" is allways displayed even if my "cars[@id='1'])='0' (Not exists).
Thanks for Help

Comment: i think there's one right parenthesis too much in that condition

Comment: im sorry its just a mistake, there is no parenthesis

Comment: post the xml too. maybe that's the other 'true'?

Comment: no  there is no athor true, just the <xsl:otherwise>
      true
 </xsl:otherwise> is allways returned, i think  <xsl:when test="cars[@id='1']='1'">true</xsl:when> is not satisfied

Comment: We really need to see the input XML, at least the context node for that `xsl:choose`. Also you might want to explain in plain English what condition you want to check, then we can tell whether your XPath expression does that or suggest an appropriate expression.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your input isn't matching at all?

```
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="cars[@id='1']">    
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="cars[@id='1']='1'">true</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:when>
 <xsl:otherwise>
      true <!-- change this and see what it returns -->
 </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: i changed it, "tutu" for example and curiously "tutu" was returned.

Answer (score 0):

From the information given, there could be any number of reasons. Common beginner's mistakes would suggest the following possibilities:

(a) the 'cars' element is actually in a namespace

(b) your context node for executing this code is not the parent of the 'cars' element